# Check whether the input is integer float or string or something else?

Tags: python-3.x

I recently participated in a programming competition online and the above question was asked.

My code:

```
abc=input()
if (abc.isnumeric()):
    print("This input is of type Integer")  
elif (abc.replace('.','').isdigit()):
    print("This input is of type Float")
elif (abc.replace('-','').isdigit()):
    print("This input is of type Integer")
elif (((abc.replace('-','')).replace('.','')).isdigit()):
    print("This input is of type Float")
elif (abc.isalnum):
    print("This input is of type string")
else:
    print("This is something else.")
```

In Python it works for different test cases but the online submission says wrong and I got 0/100 for it.

What is wrong and how can it be made proper?

Comment: i am sorry i saw one rule that the code should be under 25000bytes and i think even if the solution provided here is not under that is there any other language in which the size can be reduced to under 24KB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are unnecessarily complicating things with string manipulations. You could acheive the same with nested try-catch statements. This code should be simple enough:

```
abc = input()
try:
    test = int(abc)
    print("This input is of type Integer")
except:
    try:
        test = float(abc)
        print("This input is of type Float")
    except:
        print("This input is of type String")
```

Having stated above. The score of the code depends highly on how the test code is coded. That is, handling of multiple test cases and how it expects the output to be formatted for each test case, and so on.

**Edit:**

From the discussion in the comments it seems like you are missing the period (ful-stop) at the end of each sentence and starting letter of 'String' should be in lower case. I doubt the last case ("This is something else.") would ever occur. Also, if code size needs to be reduced further then the following code ought to work.

```
abc = input();
if len(abc) == 0: print("This is something else.")
else:
    print("This input is of type", end=" ")
    try: int(abc); print("Integer.")
    except:
        try: float(abc); print("Float.")
        except: print("string.")
```

This is assuming that no input means "something else." Personally, I don't endorse *this* level of compactness.

Comment: yes it works but when i submitted the program i still got test case failed and the program is some 200kb and i forgot to mention that it should be under 25000bytes

Comment: @user33207: You are going to have to state the full set of constraints.

Comment: yes i noticed about the size constraint just now but the program size cannot be reduced ...what to do? please use the link to try the challenge

Comment: @user33207: (1) The size can be easily reduced. (2) I'm not interested in registering a new site for another contest. (3) Give your output constraints -- how they expect the output to be formatted.

Comment: both of the above pics show the input output with example and the output i got after compiling your code

Comment: it works when i give output and try it myself but if i compile it shows test case failed even though the input and expected output is matching

Comment: i understood my stupidity the expected output had a full stop(period) at the end of the statement and i didnt use it in any of my code :(

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the way to check what a parameter is, is to use the `type()` function that is built into python.

for example

```
abc = "a string"
```

the expression

```
print (type(abc))
```

will return

```
<type 'str'>
```

Also this can be done by:

```
type(abc) is str
```

Returns

```
True
```

And

```
type(abc) is list
```

Returns

```
False
```

I would imagine that this online submission will use automated checking and may look for this function being utilised.

Comment: One major flaw, the data type for anything returned from `input()` is always `str`.